# gl_PointCoord always zero

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, particle-system

I'm drawing particles using

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The vertex shader is very simple:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

The fragment shader tries to use `gl_PointCoord`:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_PointCoord.s, gl_PointCoord.t, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

But the points are always black, so `gl_PointCoord` is always `(0.0, 0.0)`.

This is on OpenGL ES 2.0, tested on an iPhone 5 and an iPad 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
```